# Visual Studio 2010 - C++ - External Dependencies - Hiding files in selected folders

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Visual Studio 2010, C++ project.

Is it possible to hide files in the External Dependencies list based on their folder?

I would like to hide all files that are stored in

- X:\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\vc\include
- X:\Program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v.7.0a\include

So I could have a 'clean' view of files that I really forgot to add to my project.